# How to print lower matrix in cholesky with gsl?

Tags: c++, gsl

I'm using gsl with c++ to solve a linear system with Cholesky method, all works fine but i want to obtain and print the lower matrix L. I don't find anything about this question in the official documentation. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>


using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    double a_data[] = { 4, -1, 1,
                        -1, 4.25, 2.75,
                        1, 2.75, 3.5};

    double b_data[] = {1, 2, 3};

    gsl_matrix_view A = gsl_matrix_view_array (a_data, 3, 3);
    gsl_vector_view b = gsl_vector_view_array (b_data, 3);
    gsl_permutation * p = gsl_permutation_alloc (3);
    gsl_vector *x = gsl_vector_alloc (3);
    gsl_matrix *L = gsl_matrix_alloc (3, 3);



    gsl_linalg_pcholesky_decomp(& A.matrix, p);
    gsl_linalg_pcholesky_solve(& A.matrix, p, &b.vector, x);
    cout<<"x = "<<endl;
    gsl_vector_fprintf (stdout, x, "%g");
    cout<<"p = "<<endl;
    gsl_permutation_fprintf (stdout, p, "%d");
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"L = "<<endl;
    gsl_matrix_fprintf (stdout, L, "%g");

    gsl_permutation_free (p);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lower matrix L is overwritten in the original matrix A. The lower triangle part of matrix A, stores L.